# What is c# AVRO schema for Date

Tags: c#, avro, apache-kafka-streams

I have a java kafka streams application which consumes avro events produced by a C# application. On the C#, it's a built-in-house avro library. For the Date type field, it generates avro schema to `{ "name": "dateOfBirth", "type": "int" }` without logicalType. Obviously, this causes trouble in the java consumer side.

I would like to ask anyone using AVRO C#, what's the avro schema of date field generated by the standard C# avro lib?

Answer (score 0):

> Obviously, this causes trouble in the java consumer side.

It shouldn't. The schema registry would store that schema as-is, then the consumer would then read that data as an integer.

I would like to point out, however, that dates should be `long`, represented as unix epoch.

> by the standard C# avro lib?

That is exactly what the C# confluent-dotnet uses, AFAIK; they don't re-write their own

Comment: `It shouldn't. The schema registry would store that schema as-is, then the consumer would then read that data as an integer.`

Yes and no. Yes, the consumer side does use the writer's schema, which is type INT; No, it also use the generated java class by the consumer's avro library, which marks this field as a LogicalType. 

Also, accroding to the AVRO spec, A date logical type annotates an Avro int

`That is exactly what the C# confluent-dotnet uses, AFAIK; they don't re-write their own`

I would expect the standard lib create a INT fieild with LogcialType

Comment: Do you want the "number of days" since epoch, though? That is not what I would call a `date`, especially for birthday. That is really saying "days between birthday and epoch", **not** "day born". Date **times** commonly milli/micro second precision, which _should_ be a `long` to represent **(milli/micro)seconds since 1970** and planning on having dates for the next few centuries. If you are using the Schema Registry, your reader and writer schema would be the same (at least before parsing). Seems like you are storing "age", but a logicalType would store it incorrectly.

Comment: While setting the avro schema use the datetime field as int64 in c# (i.e long) and in the schema don't include the logical types. "logicalType" : "timestamp-millis"
Example: {
     "name" : "incStartDate",
     "type" : {
    "type" : "long"
     }
Hope it helps